# I cannot create a dialogbox in Java

Tags: java, swing

so i'm trying to create a dialogbox in another jframe, but when i click on the button, an empty dialogbox appears. I think it is because of the this statement, and the creation of the dialog below cannot work together. I get an error no suitable constructor found for AddConsultantDialog(no arguments) How can I write the code instead?. The creation of the dialog box in the automatically created code by netbeans. Thanks in advance.

```
public class AddConsultantDialog extends javax.swing.JDialog {

private ConsultantDAO consultantDAO;

private ConsultantSearchApp consultantSearchApp;    

public AddConsultantDialog(ConsultantSearchApp theConsoltantSearchApp, ConsultantDAO theConsultantDAO) {
    this();
    consultantDAO = theConsultantDAO;
    consultantSearchApp = theConsoltantSearchApp;
}


    /**
 * Creates new form AddConsultantDialog
 * @param parent
 * @param modal
 */
public AddConsultantDialog(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
    super(parent, modal);
    initComponents();
}
```

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do with the "this();" statement. Take it out. It appears the compiler is attempting to find a no-arg constructor *because* you have that statement in there.

Comment: Note that components without default, 0 argument constructors, are not beans.  If this code was auto-generated, it's likely because you told your IDE you wanted to create a JavaBean, but that's probably not what you wanted.  As others have said, take out the `this()`

Comment: However, if you did want this to be a JavaBean, then you should add a `AddConsultantDialog()` constructor (with no arguments).  There are a few other constraints, listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans).

Answer (score 2):

You've got at leat two constructors, one that appropriately calls the super's constructor and `initComponents()`:

```
public AddConsultantDialog(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
    super(parent, modal);
    initComponents();
}
```

and  the other that does not:

```
public AddConsultantDialog(ConsultantSearchApp theConsoltantSearchApp, ConsultantDAO theConsultantDAO) {
    this();
    consultantDAO = theConsultantDAO;
    consultantSearchApp = theConsoltantSearchApp;
}
```

I'm guessing that you're actually calling the second constructor the one without the key elements found in the second, and the problem with this is, since it does not call the appriate super constructor, the dialog is not created as a modal dialog, and also it does not call `initComponents()` and so no components are added to your GUI -- so fix it. Have your new constructor appropriately call the super's constructor, passing in a parent window, and calling `initComponents()`.

One easy fix is to call the `this(...)` that takes two parameters, a GUI and a boolean.

```
public AddConsultantDialog(ConsultantSearchApp theConsoltantSearchApp, ConsultantDAO theConsultantDAO) {
    // you will need to pass in the parent window as a parameter for this to work
    this(parentWindow, true);  // note change. It calls the first constructor above
    consultantDAO = theConsultantDAO;
    consultantSearchApp = theConsoltantSearchApp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this constructor

```
public AddConsultantDialog(ConsultantSearchApp theConsoltantSearchApp, ConsultantDAO theConsultantDAO) {
     this();
     consultantDAO = theConsultantDAO;
     consultantSearchApp = theConsoltantSearchApp;
```

}

to this

```
public AddConsultantDialog(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal, ConsultantSearchApp theConsoltantSearchApp, ConsultantDAO theConsultantDAO) {
     super(parent, modal);
     initComponents();
     consultantDAO = theConsultantDAO;
     consultantSearchApp = theConsoltantSearchApp;
```

}